# How to convert int stored in char array to int variable for calculations?

Tags: c

I need to go through each location of my char array where there are only int stored, and I need to use each number for calculations.

I have

```
char num1[a];
char num2[b];
```

Basically, I need to add `num1[1]+num2[1]` and `num1[2]+num2[2]` and so on.
How can i convert each character location to `int` for calculations?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Use atoi() function. `int n1 = atoi( num1[n] );` or `int sum = atoi( num1[0] ) + atoi( num2[0] );`

Comment: @i486 atoi() should be avoided in favor of sscanf(), since the latter can tell when conversion failed. Note that both functions operate only on NUL-terminated arrays-of-char -- an assumption we don't know if it's true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear.

If you want to add all the `int`s in the `char` array,use `isdigit()` from `ctype.h` to check if it is a digit and the add another variable `sum` accordingly

```
int i,sum=0,len=strlen(num1);
for( i=0 ; i<len ; i++ )
{
    if(isdigit(num1[i])
        sum=sum+(num1[i]-'0');
}
```

Or else if you are sure that the array contain only numbers,remove the `if` in the above code

If you want to add each integer of two different arrays,use

```
sum=(num1[i]-'0')+(num2[i]-'0');
```

Where `sum` is an `int` variable initialized to zero,`num1` and `num2` are the `char` arrays and `i` ,the index of the array which you want to add.

Answer (score 0):

`char's` are promoted to `int` implicitly with `+` operand so just you can add then as shown below:

```
  int main()
    {
        int i;
    char a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    char b[5] = {6,7,8,9,10};

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    printf("%d\n",a[i] + b[i]);
    return 0;
    }
```